# LWJGL OpenGL passing a vertex to a shader

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, vertex

If I'm passing an array of floats that contains 3 floats the represent X Y Z of a vertex without the W component and I pass it to the VBO and I tell an input variable in my shader to use the contents of the VBO but this input variable is vec4 type, Is the w component going to be set to 1 by the shader ? Also, is the vertex going to be normalized by the shader ?

## **EDIT**

MainDisplay class :

```
package com.dryadengine.gui;

import com.dryadengine.core.Model;
import com.dryadengine.framework.OBJLoader;
import com.dryadengine.framework.ShaderFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
public class MainDisplay {

    private Model bunny;
    private FloatBuffer vbo;
    private Matrix4f mProjection;
    private Matrix4f mView;
    private Matrix4f mModel;
    private int shaderProgramID;
    private int vboID;
    private int vPositionID;
    private int mProjectionID;
    private int mViewID;
    private int mModelID;
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainDisplay md = new MainDisplay();
        md.create();
        md.init();
        md.run();
    }
    
    public MainDisplay() {
        
    }
    
    public void create() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("Dryad Engine 1.0.0");
            Display.setFullscreen(false);
            Display.setResizable(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
    
    public void init() {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        try {
            shaderProgramID = ShaderFactory.createShaderProgram("vertexShader", "fragmentShader");
            glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
            bunny = OBJLoader.parseOBJ(new File("src/com/dryadengine/assets/bunny.obj"));
            vbo = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(bunny.getFaces().size() * 3 * 3);
            float[] vertexData = new float[bunny.getFaces().size() * 3 * 3];
//            System.out.println("PRINTING 10 first faces info : ");
//            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                System.out.println("FACE #" +(i+1));
//                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
//                    System.out.println("VERTEX #" +(j + 1));
//                    System.out.println(bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].x + ", " +bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].y+ ", " +bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].z);
//                }
//            }
            for (int i = 0; i < bunny.getFaces().size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    //System.out.println("placing new vertex at cell #" +((i * 3 + j) * 3));
                    vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].x;
                    //System.out.println("placing new vertex at cell #" +((i * 3 + j) * 3 + 1));
                    vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3 + 1] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].y;
                    //System.out.println("placing new vertex at cell #" +((i * 3 + j) * 3 + 2));
                    vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3 + 2] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].z;
                }
            }
            vbo.put(vertexData);
            vbo.flip();
            vboID = glGenBuffers();
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            vPositionID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "vPosition");
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionID);
            mProjection = new Matrix4f();
            float fieldOfView = 60f;
            float aspectRatio = (float)Display.getWidth() / (float)Display.getHeight();
            float nearPlane = 0.1f;
            float farPlane = 100f;
            float yScale = (float)(1.0f / Math.tan((fieldOfView / 2.0f) * (float)(Math.PI / 180d)));
            float xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
            float frustum_length = farPlane - nearPlane;
            mProjection.m00 = xScale;
            mProjection.m11 = yScale;
            mProjection.m22 = -((farPlane + nearPlane) / frustum_length);
            mProjection.m23 = -1;
            mProjection.m32 = -((2 * nearPlane * farPlane) / frustum_length);
            mProjection.m33 = 0;
            mView = new Matrix4f();
            mView.m23 = -5;
            mModel = new Matrix4f();
            mProjectionID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "mProjection");
            mViewID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "mView");
            mModelID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "mModel");
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void run() {
        int fps = 0;
        long lastCheck = System.nanoTime();
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            if (Display.isVisible()) {
                render();
            }
            if (Display.wasResized()) {
                resize(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
            }
            if (System.nanoTime() - lastCheck >= 1000000000) {
                System.out.println("FPS : " +fps);
                fps = 0;
                lastCheck = System.nanoTime();
            }
            fps++;
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        destroy();
    }
    
    public void render() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        FloatBuffer fb1 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer fb2 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer fb3 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        mProjection.store(fb1);
        mView.store(fb2);
        mModel.store(fb3);
        fb1.flip();
        fb2.flip();
        fb3.flip();
        glUniformMatrix4(mProjectionID, false, fb1);
        glUniformMatrix4(mViewID, false, fb2);
        glUniformMatrix4(mModelID, false, fb3);
        glVertexAttribPointer (vPositionID, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, bunny.getFaces().size() * 3);
    }
    
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    
    public void dispose() {
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgramID);
        glUseProgram(0);
        glDeleteBuffers(vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
        dispose();
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

ShaderFactory class :

```
package com.dryadengine.framework;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
public class ShaderFactory {
    
    private static final String COMMON_SHADERS_PATH = "/com/dryadengine/shaders/";
    private static final String SHADER_EXTENSION = ".dsf";
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param vertexShaderName
     * @param fragmentShaderName
     * @return a shader program
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static int createShaderProgram(String vertexShaderName, String fragmentShaderName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Integer> shaders = new ArrayList();
        shaders.add(ShaderFactory.compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, getShaderFileCode(COMMON_SHADERS_PATH + vertexShaderName + SHADER_EXTENSION)));
        shaders.add(ShaderFactory.compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, getShaderFileCode(COMMON_SHADERS_PATH + fragmentShaderName + SHADER_EXTENSION)));
        return ShaderFactory.linkProgram(shaders);
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param shaderFilePath
     * @return a shader file code
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private static String getShaderFileCode(String shaderFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        StringBuilder shaderCode = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ShaderFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(shaderFilePath)))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    shaderCode.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return shaderCode.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param shaderType
     * @param shaderCode
     * @return a compiled shader file id
     */
    public static int compileShader(int shaderType, String shaderCode) {
        int shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
        glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderCode);
        glCompileShader(shaderID);
        int status = glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (status == GL_FALSE) {
            glDeleteShader(shaderID);
            throw new RuntimeException(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
        }
        return shaderID;
    }
    
    /**
     * Link the vertex shader and the fragment shader to the shader program
     * @param shaders
     * @return a shader program
     */
    public static int linkProgram(ArrayList <Integer> shaders) {
        int shaderProgramID = glCreateProgram();
        for (Integer shader : shaders) {
            glAttachShader(shaderProgramID, shader);
        }
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgramID);
        int status = glGetProgrami(shaderProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS);
        if (status == GL_FALSE) {
            glDeleteProgram(shaderProgramID);
            throw new RuntimeException(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderProgramID, glGetProgrami(shaderProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
        }
        for (int shader : shaders) {
            glDeleteShader(shader);
        }
        return shaderProgramID;
    }
    
}
```

OBJLoader class :

```
package com.dryadengine.framework;

import com.dryadengine.core.Face;
import com.dryadengine.core.Model;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
public class OBJLoader {
    
    /**
     * Parse .obj file and make a model from it.
     * @param f
     * @return a model object
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static Model parseOBJ(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        Model m;
        List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Face> faces = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                vertices.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                normals.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                Vector3f[] a = new Vector3f[3];
                Vector3f[] b = new Vector3f[3];
                a[0] = vertices.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("//")[0]) - 1);
                a[1] = vertices.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("//")[0]) - 1);
                a[2] = vertices.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("//")[0]) - 1);
                b[0] = normals.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("//")[1]) - 1);
                b[1] = normals.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("//")[1]) - 1);
                b[2] = normals.get(Integer.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("//")[1]) - 1);
                faces.add(new Face(a, b));
            }
        }
        br.close();
        m = new Model(faces);
        return m;
    }
    
}
```

Model class :

```
package com.dryadengine.core;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
public class Model {
    
    private List<Face> faces;
    
    /**
     * Construct a new model object.
     * @param faces
     */
    public Model(List<Face> faces) {
        this.faces = faces;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return the faces list
     */
    public List<Face> getFaces() {
        return faces;
    }
    
}
```

Face class :

```
package com.dryadengine.core;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
public class Face {
    
    private Vector3f[] vertices;
    private Vector3f[] normals;
    
    public Face() {
        vertices = new Vector3f[3];
        normals = new Vector3f[3];
    }
    
    public Face(Vector3f[] vertices, Vector3f[] normals) {
        this();
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.normals = normals;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return the vertices array
     */
    public Vector3f[] getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return the normals array
     */
    public Vector3f[] getNormals() {
        return normals;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the vertices array
     * @param vertices 
     */
    public void setVertices(Vector3f[] vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the normals array
     * @param normals 
     */
    public void setNormals(Vector3f[] normals) {
        this.normals = normals;
    }
    
}
```

Vertex shader :

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 mProjection;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mModel;

in vec4 vPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mProjection * mView * mModel * vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader :

```
#version 330

out vec4 vOutputColor;

void main()
{
    vOutputColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The bunny.obj file I use :
http://rghost.net/54750078

Comment: What do you mean by normalizing a vertex? A vertex is a position in 3D whos length is the distance to the origin. It doesn't make sense to normalize a position because then all vertices will end up on the unit sphere.

Comment: I ment normalize the vector making it between the range of -1 and 1

Comment: That's the perspective division, which is staged in the graphics pipeline after the vertex shader has been run. The vertex shader receives positions in object space, hence the necessity to apply the modelview-projection matrix to transform from object space to clip space. The division by `w` (you call it normalizing, which it is not) is then done automatically in subsequent steps in the pipeline.

Comment: I don't need to use normalize(position) and only then multiply by the MVP matrix ? and if not why exactly ?

Comment: Like I said, normalizing a position does not make sense. Normalizing ensures the length of a vector becomes 1, which makes sense for direction vectors but not for positions. I guess what you mean is going from `(x,y,z,w)` to `(x/w,y/w,z/w,1)` which is done for you after the vertex program has run.

Comment: So could you please explain me why I'm failing to render the standford bunny to the screen ? vertex data is correct (I've checked it with the printing lines I've added in the code), and when I try to render I see black screen, could you spot the error ?

Comment: You assign three values to `vertexData[i * 3 + j]`, that is certainly incorrect. I'm also not sure if your VBO is bound correctly, I do not see any bindings in `render`. Just a note, you may benefit from pre-calculating the modelview-projection matrix to avoid lots of matrix multiplications.

Comment: its is correct is will always places the float in the next cell of the array going from 0.. to # of vertices X 3 (for X Y Z ), I've also printed to check it and it's correct. And I dont bind the vbo in the render method I bind it in the init method after the for loop because why bind it multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `w` is going to be 1.0 in this case. From the first paragraph of section 2.8.1 (Transferring Array Elements) in the OpenGL 3.3 spec:

> If size is one then the x component of the attribute is speciﬁed by the array; the y, z, and w components are implicitly set to 0, 0, and 1, respectively. If size is two then the x and y components of the attribute are speciﬁed by the array; the z and w components are implicitly set to 0 and 1, respectively. If size is three then x, y, and z are speciﬁed, and w is implicitly set to 1. If size is four then all components are speciﬁed.

Looking through the code you posted, I spotted a problem where you copy your vertex coordinates to `vertexData`:

```
vertexData[i * 3 + j] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].x;
vertexData[i * 3 + j] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].y;
vertexData[i * 3 + j] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].z;
```

This copies the x, y, and z coordinates to the same array location. It should look like this instead:

```
vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3    ] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].x;
vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3 + 1] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].y;
vertexData[(i * 3 + j) * 3 + 2] = bunny.getFaces().get(i).getVertices()[j].z;
```

Edit: I think I found one more problem. After studying LWJGL some more, it looks like the translation part of the matrix goes into `m30`, `m31`, `m32`. So I believe you need to change this for your model matrix:

```
mView.m23 = -5;
```

to this:

```
mView.m32 = -5;
```

Comment: I see but if I specify x y z and w is set to 1.0 are the z y and z component get devided by w automatically ? also can you help me find the error in my code ? I can't render the standford bunny, my OBJLoader is correct for sure I event printed in the MainDisplay code the vertices of the 10 first faces of the model and they're 100% correct, and still all I see is black screen, I've provided the MainDisplay code and my VertexShader code the error is probably there but I couldn't find it and I've been looking for more than 3 days now ..

Comment: There's no automatic division by w for vertex attributes. The only place I can think of where there is an automatic division by w is for `gl_Position` after the vertex shader, when the fixed function part of the pipeline calculates normalized device coordinates. I looked through your code, and the only problem I spotted so far is that you specify your `fieldOfView` in degrees, where you need an angle in radians. If you want more ideas on diagnosing it, here's a shameless plug for an article on my web site: http://retokoradi.com/2014/04/21/opengl-why-is-your-code-producing-a-black-window/

Comment: float yScale = (float)(1.0f / Math.tan((fieldOfView / 2.0f) * (float)(Math.PI / 180d))); - I'm pretty sure I'm using radians ? maybe you missed it ? :)

Comment: @user3573780: Sure did. The last part was cut off, and I missed to scroll right. Sorry about the false alarm.

Comment: tell me if you find the error because I still cant and its driving me crazy :X

Comment: @user3573780: I found a problem in your code. I added it to the answer. Looking back at the old comments, Joost had already spotted it earlier. Could have saved myself some time by reading all the comments first.

Comment: It was an error and thanks for spotting it but unfortunately for me it didn't fix it I still see black screen, I just updated the thread with every class and shader in the program I've also included the .obj file I use hopefully you could spot what prevents from the bunny to be rendered to the screen. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @user3573780: I added one more thing. The model matrix looks wrong. If this still doesn't work, I would try temporarily disabling `GL_CULL_FACE`, just to be sure. Also, you can try to not apply any transformations at all (`gl_Position = vPosition;`). If your bunny sits around the origin, you should see something without any transformation.

Comment: Ok so after changing it I get this : [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/5mlu9j.png[/IMG] why is it so small ?

Comment: I see a bunny! The link to the model didn't work for me, so I don't know what the range of coordinates is. You're currently 5 units away, with a large field of view. Reduce the field of view and/or the distance in your viewing matrix (`m32` value), and it should come closer.